# C++ sfml how to rotate a character from its center

Tags: c++, rotation, sfml

I want to use the function sprite.rotate() and sprite.setrotation() but sfml takes into account the top-right point of the sprite. How to set this point to sprite center?

Comment: Do you have the [SFML manual](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/)?

Comment: There is a class called `RectangleShape` for doing that. Search and read about how you can utilize it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the rotation center you have to use `sprite.setOrigin()` function which sets the center for position and rotation.

For example:

```
sf::Texture texture;
if (!texture.loadFromFile("texture.png"))
    exit(-1);

sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.setOrigin((sf::Vector2f)texture.getSize() / 2.f);
```

Or if you are changing the texture rect of the sprite:

```
sprite.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(sprite.getLocalBounds().width, sprite.getLocalBounds().height) / 2.f);
```